# Read status of messages in Inbox

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a messaging inbox system that uses a thread-based layout for messages. What I'm struggling with at the moment is updating the read status of the messages. Perhaps I have got the structure wrong so I could do with some guidance.

Here is what I have:

```
Table messages
==============
id
thread_id
from_user_id
subject
body
sent_date

Table message_threads
=====================
id
message_id
owner_id
member_id
owner_read
member_read
```

In the message_threads table, 'owner' refers to the user who started the thread, and 'member' refers to the other participant. A user's inbox will contain threads they have created themselves (owner), and also threads created by other users to which they have replied to (member).

The logic for setting the read status is as follows:

- if owner sends a reply: 'member_read' field is set to 0 (unread), 'owner_read' field is set to 1 (read)
- if member sends a reply: 'owner_read' field is set to 0 (unread), 'member_read' field is set to 1 (read)

Now I don't think this is entirely the correct approach, because suppose a member wants to sort messages in their inbox by read status - however a user can be both an owner and a member, and there are two read fields in the table. So this sort would not be correct.

Any suggestions on how I should go about this?

EDIT: Here is an exaple scenario:

- User 1 sends Thread A to User 2

  - Thread A appears in User 2's inbox (status 0: unread)

---

- User 2 opens Thread A

  - Thread A status set to 1 (read)

---

- User 2 replies to Thread A

  - Thread A status in User 1's inbox (status 0: unread)
  - Thread A status in User 2's inbox (status 1: read)

---

- User 1 opens Thread A

  - Thread A status set to 1 (read)

---

- User 1 replies to Thread A

  - Thread A status in User 1's inbox (status 1: read)
  - Thread A status in User 2's inbox (status 0: unread)

Comment: so... a thread is only ever read by two people?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's a 1-1 conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The only "read" status is for messages that didn't originate from you. a reply to a recipient is marked read when opened. The sender doesn't care if it was read unless you want "receipt confirmation"

So - with that in mind here is what i think it should look like (i didn't include all fields in messages):

Table "users"

```
id
name
```

table "messages"

```
id (int)
parent_id (int)
from_user_id (id)
to_user_id
read (bit/bool)
message (text)
```

Let me know if I didn't understand you right.

Comment: I see. So your approach is to have a read status on the actual message, rather than the thread. But since the user's inbox will be displaying threads rather than individual messages, would this work?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a view in addition to just the tables

Comment: Assuming parent_id is 0 (top conversation) you could have another table where you track threads by message_id, user_id, is_read. This table should hold only the ID of the message that started the thread. join to this table when showing messages and now you can show/hide based on their read status.

Comment: i am thinking here that any message has the potential to be part of a thread so long as it has a parent_id.

Comment: Well that's what I thought too - but as I mention in my original post, the difficulty is that a user can be an owner of a thread, and a recipient of another thread. And because there are two read status fields, the sorting will not be correct. The inbox is unified - this is exactly how Facebook inbox works.